# C++, #ifdef question

Tags: c++

Not coding in C++ right now but a question came up when I have a question in C#. Hope experts here can easily give a anwser.

```
Class A{
  #ifdef AFlag
  public void methodA(){...}
  #endif
}

Class B{
...
  A a;
  a.methodA();
...
}

Class C {
...
  A a;
  a.methodA();
...
}
```

If the AFlag is NOT defined anywhere, what will happen? A compile error or no error but the methodA AND those statements calling that method will not be compiled?
thanks

Comment: This is an example of the complications of using `#if` to delineate feature specific code.  The classes `B` and `C` would need to use the same `#if`.  Thus it propagates to any code fragment using `A::methodA()`.  This is how nightmares begin and corporate profits wasted.  Another reason to prefer function replacement (by linkers) (or including all the code and using a configuration data file).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There will be a compile error.

Answer (score 4):

Preprocessing happens *before* compilation. By the time your code goes to the compiler, the definition of method A in class A will be removed. Effectively its as if as you never wrote it. So this will result in compilation error.

Comment: +1 for including the crucial point: The preprocessor has a go at your source file *BEFORE* the compiler even sees it. The compiler never has a chance to see any preprocessor symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Class A will not have an `methodA` so compiling class B or C will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a complier error, as the function `methodA` is not declared anywhere.  You could use this syntax instead:

```
Class A{ 

  public void methodA()
  {
#ifdef AFlag 
    ...
#endif 
  } 

}
```

Which will allow `methodA` to be declared / defined, but it will be optimized away if you turn optimizations on.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say for certain, since code in the "..." could affect the answer, or mean that I've misunderstood the question. The statement `a.methodA();` has to be in the body of a function.

You'll get compile errors at the lines `a.methodA();` (or perhaps linker errors if the code is split across multiple translation units with inconsistent definitions of class A). Calling a function means it has to be there. The call is not "ignored" if the function doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If `AFlag` is not defined, class `A` won't have a member function `methodA()`, so the calls to it in class `B` and `C` will be errors.

Answer (score 0):

You would see a compile error as the method methodA is not defined on class A.